# How to display a loading indicator or placeholder image in React Native Image before the main source loads without causing double loading?

Tags: javascript, react-native, image, web, expo

I am working with React Native and trying to implement a loading indicator or a placeholder image in the standard `Image` component before the main source is loaded. The requirement is to display either a loading GIF with a spinner or an . I've noticed that the `Image` component from `react-native-elements` provides a `PlaceholderContent` property, but it lacks the `onLoadEnd` event, and external libraries are not recommended.

When I try to use the `DefaultSource` property in the `Image` component, the image is loaded twice(from my source link). Here is an example of my code:

```
<Image
  source={{
    uri: `${baseURL}/api/Images/ResizeImage`,
  }}
  style={{ height: 300, width: 300, resizeMode: 'cover'}}
  onLoadEnd={handleImageLoad}
  defaultSource={loading} // This causes double loading
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In principle, I managed to use the indicator to load the image through `Image` events.

```js
import React, { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { View, Image, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";

const CustomImage = ({ style, source }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const handleLoadStart = () => {
    setLoading(true);
  };

  const handleLoadEnd = () => {
    setLoading(false);
  };

  const handleLoad = () => {
    setLoading(false);
  };

  const memorizedImage = useMemo(() => (
      <Image
        style={style}
        source={source}
        onLoadStart={handleLoadStart}
        onLoadEnd={handleLoadEnd}
        onLoad={handleLoad}
      />
  ), [source])

  return (
    <View>
      {loading && (
        <ActivityIndicator color="#008000" style={{ ...style, position: 'absolute'}}/>
      )}
      {memorizedImage}
    </View>
  );
};

export default CustomImage;
```